# How to auth user to Django admin site using external API end point

Tags: python, django

I'm using an external endpoint to check if the username and password are given and if it is valid I return `success:true` if not I return it as `false`. and ofc I generate a token and return it back to him.

Here is the function amusing for this :

```py
@api_view(["POST"])  # decorator to make this a rest API endpoint
def login_user(request):
    """
    Login User Endpoint takes in email & password as input from the client side
    """
    username, password = request.data["username"], request.data["password"]
    # authenticate function from Django auth library is used here
    # to check if the provided credentials are correct or not
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    # If authentication is successful then generate a token else return an error message as a JSON object
    if user:
        token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        the_company_object = hiring_app_company.objects.get(user=user)
        user_object = {
            "name": f"{user.first_name} {user.last_name}",
            "email": user.username,
            "image": f"https://admin.apexnile.com{the_company_object.company_logo.url}",
            "link":f"https://admin.apexnile.com/admin/"
        }
        return Response(
            {"success": True, "user": user_object, "token": token.key},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )
    else:
        return Response(
            {"success": False, "error": "Invalid Credentials"},
            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        )
```

The API called are being called from a totally different server which uses `Next auth` and it authenticates the user based on the response returned from this API call.
now the problem is sometimes I need this authed user to go to the Django admin site and use a few features there .. but based on the logic used here .. he is not Authenticated in the Django site and he has to rewrite his username and password to login .. any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an external API endpoint that handles user authentication and generates tokens, you can integrate this external authentication with Django's admin site using a custom authentication backend.

1. Create a custom authentication backend:
   In your Django project, create a custom authentication backend that will handle the authentication process using the token generated by your external API. This backend will override Django's built-in authentication backend.

Create a Python file for your custom backend, for example, custom_auth_backend.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class ExternalAPITokenBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        # Implement your logic to validate the user's token with the external API
        # You can make a request to the external API to validate the token
        # If the token is valid, fetch the user and return it, else return None

        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(key=password)  # Assuming password contains the token
            user = User.objects.get(username=token.user.username)
            return user
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

2. Configure your custom authentication backend:
   In your project's settings (settings.py), add your custom authentication backend to the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS list:

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',  # Default Django backend
    'your_project.custom_auth_backend.ExternalAPITokenBackend',
]
```

3. Use the external API to authenticate:
   Now, when you receive a token from the external API, you can use this token to authenticate the user in your Django admin site. You don't need to ask the user for their username and password again. Simply use the token to authenticate the user in your views or middleware.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import login

def authenticate_user(request, token):
    user = ExternalAPITokenBackend().authenticate(request, password=token)
    if user:
        login(request, user,backend='your_project.custom_auth_backend.ExternalAPITokenBackend')  # Log the user in
        return True
    return False
```

4. To use the custom authentication backend in Django admin, you need to override the default admin login view to use your custom authentication logic. This way, when users access the Django admin, they can be authenticated using the token generated by your external API. Here's how to achieve this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class CustomAdminLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'admin/login.html'  # Customize the login template if needed

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user)
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            # Authentication failed using the traditional method.
            # You can add additional logic to handle this case if needed.
            return super().form_invalid(form)

def admin_logout(request):
    # Define a custom logout view if needed
    # This can be used to handle any additional cleanup or actions upon logout.
    # For example, you can also log the user out of the external API here.
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

In your project's urls.py, override the Django admin login URL to use your custom login view:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from your_app.views import CustomAdminLoginView, admin_logout

admin.site.login = CustomAdminLoginView.as_view()
admin.site.logout = admin_logout  # Optional custom logout view
```

Comment: does this  `CustomAdminLoginView` function have anything to do with the API token as it is written now, or do I have to implement more logic to it?